# What is dasd_data_dollection in analytics?

Tags: ios, privacy

On my iPhone 7, in Settings -> Privacy -> Analytics and Improvements -> Analytics Data, one of the items on the list is "dasd_data_collection"

Tbh, I don't understand what most things in the Analytics Data list are, but the name of this one jumped out at me particularly.

Does anyone know what this specific item is?